# TextBox is not creating newline when reading text file C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this program that supposed to reads multiple text files on the same folder, in that folder there's 2 text files which are supposed to be read, ok now I have to generate a new TextBox based on the total numbers of text files in that folder.

##### Main Goal

Load the contents of those files in each textbox

- File1.txt contents will be loaded into TextBox1.
- File2.txt contents will be loaded into TextBox2.

Content of File1.txt:

```
Title 1
ABCDEFG
```

Content of File2.txt:

```
Title 2
1234567890
```

#### The problem

Loading the contents of those files into each TextBoxes works fine, but the problem is that the newline isn't created on the TextBoxes.

Instead I got this on each textboxes:

TextBox 1:

```
Title 1ABCDEFG
```

TextBox 2:

```
Title 21234567890
```

Do the necessary stuff as soon the program loads:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;

        var dirs_notes = @"C:\MAIN_LOC\DATA_LOC\";
        var count_notes = Directory.GetFiles(dirs_notes,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();

        string setup_path = @"C:\MAIN_LOC\DATA_LOC\";
        if(Directory.Exists(setup_path)) {
            string[] get_notes = Directory.GetFiles(dirs_notes, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] get_texts = get_notes.Select(x => File.ReadAllText(x)).ToArray();

            for(int i=0; i<count_notes; i++) {
                int top = 25;
                int h_p = 170;
                var load_note = new Guna2TextBox() {
                    Text = "\n" + get_texts[i],
                    Name = "Note" + i,
                    Multiline = true,
                    AcceptsTab = true,
                    AcceptsReturn = true,
                    WordWrap = false,
                    Width = 230,
                    Height = 145,
                    BorderRadius = 8,
                    Font = new Font("Bahnschrift", 13),
                    ForeColor = Color.White,
                    FillColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#1E1E1E"),
                    BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2C2C2C"),
                    Location = new Point(450, top)
                };
                top += h_p;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(load_note);
                }
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("There's problem with loading notes..", "Flow Notes System");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Use ReadLines instead of ReadAllText and then set the Lines property of the textbox with the lines returned by ReadLines

Comment: @Steve Line  `string[] get_texts = get_notes.Select(x => File.ReadLines(x)).ToArray();` throws `Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<string>[] to string[]` error..

Comment: Also I can see a potential error and some very needed optimizations here. The files count could not match if you have other kind of files thant TXT in that directory and the result will be an IndexOutOfRangeException. Finally the way you read the files and keep their content in memory could be very a performance pit if you have big text files or a lot of files.

Comment: Firstly, yes you're right but I have piece of code that supposed to makes sure in that folder there could be only .txt files and no more other than that. Secondly, in my case performance doesn't matter as much.

Comment: _var get_texts_ and then _Lines = get_texts[i].ToArray()_ and remove the ToArray in the Select line

Comment: @Steve Thank you so much, sometimes I forgot how useful `var` dtype can be.

Comment: What happens if you change `Text = "\n" + get_texts[i]` to `Text = "\r\n" + get_texts[i]` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I've done that and it doesn't create a new line on the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix could be using the Lines property instead of the Text property.

```
var dirs_notes = @"C:\MAIN_LOC\DATA_LOC\";

// Be sure to count only txt files here...
var count_notes =  Directory.GetFiles(dirs_notes,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();

string setup_path = @"C:\MAIN_LOC\DATA_LOC\";
if(Directory.Exists(setup_path)) {
    string[] get_notes = Directory.GetFiles(dirs_notes, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var get_texts = get_notes.Select(x => File.ReadLines(x));

    for(int i=0; i<count_notes; i++) {
        ....
        var load_note = new Guna2TextBox() {
        Lines = "\n" + get_texts[i].ToArray(),
```

But a better approach is to use this instead:

```
// No counting here (counting means load all 
// files names in a memory array and the get its length
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirs_notes,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories)


int i = 1;
// Enumerate files one by one without loading all names in memory
foreach(string file in files) {
   int top = 25;
   int h_p = 170;
   var load_note = new Guna2TextBox() {
       // Set the textbox with the current file lines content
       // again one by one without loading all texts in memory
       Lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToArray(),
       Name = "Note" + i,
       ...
   }
   i++;
   .....
}
```